# Kerberos authentication works when the domain is added in host file

Tags: kerberos

I have implemented kerberos authentication to a public website [like www.microsoft.com]. when I invoke it for authentication, The ticket returned is very short and it is not accepted by the AD server.

But If I add the load balancer IP to end-user's host file, proper ticket is returned and it is accepted by AD. I am confused about this behavior of Kerberos. Could someone shed some light on this.

Comment: The MIT Kerberos client *(caveat: Microsoft may have a different policy)* checks that the server name is a **canonical DNS entry**, not an alias, not an IP. In practise it resolves the name into an IP, then the IP into a name, and checks that it's the same exact name. If it's not the case it blocks the connection attempt *(alert - possible IP spoofing!)* ===> if your DNS entry is screwed up *(which is common in a corporate data center, using per-application aliases instead of "physical" host name)* the workaround is, indeed, to short-circuit the DNS check with a custom `hosts` file.

Comment: TL;DR  https://web.mit.edu/kerberos/krb5-1.13/doc/admin/princ_dns.html

Comment: Thanks Samson. I am exploring them. I found that that the host which I have keytab hav alias and the call goes to KDC after resolving the alias name. Thats causing defective ticket returned issue.

Comment: Since I added an entry to my host file, IE resolved it and goes to KDC to get the ticket with same host name. Is there a way I can enforce the browser to use actual host name in browser to go to KDC rather than resolving it to alias?

Comment: That looks like a different question... my guess is that the browser uses OS system calls, and has to, because that's really low-level stuff (with possibly weird configuration e.g. multiple network cards, multiple IPs bound to the same card, multiple VM "hosts" bridged to an IP, etc.)